# Prove that $p^2+q^2=r^2+s^2+t^2$ doesn't have a solution in prime numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I have a homework problem that asks for a proof that
$$p^2+q^2=r^2+s^2+t^2$$ doesn't have a solution where $p,q,r,s,t$ are prime.

I tried considering this equation modulo 2, but that got me nowhere:

If none of the variables are equal to $2$, then the equation does not have a solution, since $p^2+q^2\equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$ and $r^2+s^2+t^2\equiv 1 \ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$. That's a good start. From this thinking we can figure out that in order for the equation to be able to have a prime solution, 1, 3 or all 5 variables have to be even (so, since they're prime, $2$). We can, of course, easily rule out the case where all 5 variables are equal to $2$, since $8\neq 12$. Even the case where 3 of them are equal to $2$ isn't that bad. This case comes down to two subcases:
$$p^2+q^2=12$$
for which it is easy to check no solutions exist, and
$$p^2+4=8+t^2 \Longrightarrow (p-t)(p+t)=4$$
for which it is again easy to show no solutions exist.

The real problem is the case where only one of these primes is equal to $2$. Again, two subcases exist:
$$p^2+q^2=4+s^2+t^2$$
and
$$p^2+4=r^2+s^2+t^2$$
I tried moving terms over and factoring, plugging in different values and checking and nothing seems to work. Is my approach wrong or is there a way to make this proof work? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, if none of them are $3$ then you get $2\equiv 0\pmod 3$ so you also know that one  of them is $3$.

Comment: Also note that working $\pmod 4$ rules out one of your cases/

Comment: Usually for this type of equation, the first think to do is to consider it modulo 8: an odd square is always congruent to 1 modulo 8, and an even one to 0 or 4 modulo 8. So, you get very quickly the needed information: the square of odd primes is 1 modulo 8, and the square of 2 is 4 modulo 8. Now, just examine methodically all the possibilities modulo 8.

Comment: @DDomjosa FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2%2Bq%5E2%3Dr%5E2%2Bs%5E2%2Bt%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [An interesting number problem for junior students](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h2487741p20922935), [number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1527730p9169644) and [prove there is no solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1597795p9928146).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you work out that there are an odd number of twos, *every* case is ruled out by working modulo $8$, where the squares of all odd primes are congruent to $1$. It remains to write down the cases:
$$4+4\not\equiv4+4+4\\
1+1\not\equiv4+4+4\\
1+4\not\equiv1+4+4\\
4+4\not\equiv1+1+4\\
1+1\not\equiv1+1+4\\
1+4\not\equiv1+1+1$$

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and concise answer!